# Add coupon to order using WooCommerce API v3

Tags: woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I'm trying to apply a discount coupon when creating an order via WooCommerce v3 API. I'm testing this using Postman.

Without the `coupon_lines`, I am able to create the order.
[image]

But with `coupon_lines`, I get error 500.
[image]

Here's the JSON that I'm using:

```
{
    "payment_method": "payment_method_sb_test",
    "payment_method_title": "Test/Paymentless gateway ",
    "set_paid": true,
    "billing": {
        "first_name": "Test",
        "last_name": "Customer",
        "address_1": "1 Macquarie Street",
        "address_2": "",
        "city": "Parramatta",
        "state": "NSW",
        "postcode": "2150",
        "country": "AU",
        "email": "test123@gmail.com",
        "phone": "1234567"
    },
    "shipping": {
        "first_name": "Test",
        "last_name": "Customer",
        "address_1": "1 Macquarie Street",
        "address_2": "",
        "city": "Parramatta",
        "state": "NSW",
        "postcode": "2150",
        "country": "AU"
    },
    "line_items": [
        {
            "product_id": "96153",
            "quantity": 1
        }
    ],
    "shiprate": {
        "method_id": "flat_rate",
        "method_title": "Standard Flat Rate",
        "total": "9.86"
    },
    "customer_note": "Test order",
    "coupon_lines": [
        {
            "code": "417AF65F7D07186FDB",
            "amount": "5"
        }
    ]
}
```

What am I missing? Please help.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: First thing to do, when you get a 500 Internal Server Error: Check the relevant log files.

Comment: @CBroe thank you. Your comment is very useful. Yes, I checked the logs, and the error is not very descriptive. And I've also read the documentation and did a lot of research before I asked here. Here's the link to the documentation. There's no good example of how to apply coupon when creating orders: https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#create-an-order

Comment: https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#order-coupon-lines-properties lists properties `code` and `discount` - whereas you are trying to set `code` and `amount`.

Comment: Thank you. I also tried "code" and "discount". "discount" is actually for percentage according to the documentation. "amount" is used when applying an exact value. I tried searching for similar questions on StackOverflow but those are from years ago, using v1 and v2 API. On v3, it appears to be broken. I found many issues with the latest WooCommerce API, and this is just one of the things that seems to have stopped working.